# How to list Pods based on Labels in kubernetes go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, kubernetes-go-client

I have tried to list pods based on labels

```
    // Kubernetes client - package kubernetes
    clientset := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(config)

    // create a temp list for storage 
    var podslice []string

    // Get pods -- package metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    for _, p := range pods.Items {
        fmt.Println(p.GetName())
    }
```

this is equivalent of

```
kubectl get po
```

is there a way to get in golang

```
kubectl get po -l app=foo
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may just be able to set using the `ListOptions` parameter.

```
listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
        LabelSelector: "app=foo",
    }
pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(listOptions)
```

If you have multiple labels, you may be able to perform this via the `labels` library, like below untested code:

```
import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"

labelSelector := metav1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels: map[string]string{"app": "foo"}}
listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: labels.Set(labelSelector.MatchLabels).String(),
}
pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(listOptions)
```